# adding view without storyboard with dynamic size and frame

Tags: swift, user-interface, dynamic, autolayout

I'm trying to write a custom view (next button), which change it's width and position whenever the keyboard is displayed / hidden. My goal is to build it as generic as possible, and do not create it again and again in each storyboard. Therefore, its constraints totally defined in code.

My problem is that I don't know how to update existed constraints through code. As far as I know, an
`bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: safeAreaBottomInset + 32.0)` will create a new constraint.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable

```
var cons:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then

```
cons = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: safeAreaBottomInset + 32.0)
```

Finally

Play with it's `constant` / `multiplier` / `isActive` properties to change it or re-create a new one